# How to retrieve a shared preferences value in static method

Tags: java, android

this is my shared preferences method

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("APPSTATUS", 1);
        editor.putLong("eventId", eventMO.getEventId());
        editor.commit();
        Log.i("App", "start");
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityContext(context);
    }
```

here the eventid value stored in shared preferences . i need to get this event_id value in following static method to compare the event_id

```
 public static void messageHandler(final Context context ,final MessageMO messageMo) {

        UIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        UIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1;
                Log.e("messageHandler", messageMo.getEventTitle());
                ChatMO chatMO = new ChatMO();
                chatMO.setMessage(messageMo.getMessage());
                chatMO.setSelf(0);
                chatMO.setFromName(messageMo.getfromUserName());
                chatMO.setDate(messageMo.getDate());
                chatMO.setEvent_id(messageMo.getEventId());
                Log.e("handler", "eventid" + chatMO.getEvent_id());
                Log.e("handler", "date" + chatMO.getDate());
                listChatMessageObjectses.add(chatMO);
                Log.e("handler", "listmessage" + listChatMessageObjectses);

                    }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read those values using below code snippet. You need context to get preference instance which you can store locally in the same class.

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

int appStatus = pref.getInt("APPSTATUS", 1);

long eventId = pref.getLong("eventId", 0);
```